# Optimal choice algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

i have an appointment for university which is due today and i start getting nervous. We recently discussed dynamic programming for algorithm optimization and now we shall implement an algorithm ourself which uses dynamic programming.

## Task

So we have a simple game for which we shall write an algorithm to find the best possible strategy to get the best possible score (assuming both players play optimized).

We have a row of numbers like `4 7 2 3` (note that according to the task description it is not asured that it always is an equal count of numbers). Now each player turnwise takes a number from the back or the front. When the last number is picked the numbers are summed up for each player and the resulting scores for each player are substracted from each other. The result is then the score for player 1. So an optimal order for the above numbers would be

P1: 3 -> p2: 4 -> p1: 7 -> p2: 2

So p1 would have `3, 7` and p2 would have `4, 2` which results in a final score of `(3 + 7) - (4 + 2) = 4` for player 1.

In the first task we should simply implement "an easy recursive way of solving this" where i just used a minimax algorithm which seemed to be fine for the automated test. In the second task however i am stuck since we shall now work with dynamic programming techniques. The only hint i found was that in the task itself a `matrix` is mentioned.

## What i know so far

We had an example of a word converting problem where such a matrix was used it was called `Edit distance` of two words which means how many changes (**I**nsertions, **D**eletions, **S**ubstitutions) of letters does it take to change one word into another. There the two words where ordered as a table or matrix and for each combination of the word the distance would be calculated.

Example:

```
W    H    A         T
     | D       | I
     v         v
W         A    N    T
```

editing distance would be 2. And you had a table where each editing distance for each substring was displayed like this:

```
   ""    W    H    A    T
         1    2    3    4
       
   W 1   0    1    2    3
   
   A 2   1    1    2    3
   
   N 3   2    2    2    3
   
   T 4   3    3    3    2
```

So for example from `WHA` to `WAN` would take 2 edits: insert N and delete H, from `WH` to `WAN` would also take 2 edits: substitude H->A and insert N and so on. These values where calculated with an "OPT" function which i think stands for optimization.
I also leanred about bottom-up and top-down recursive schemes but im not quite sure how to attach that to my problem.

## What i thought about

As a reminder i use the numbers `4 7 2 3`.

i learned from the above that i should try to create a table where each possible result is displayed (like minimax just that it will be saved before). I then created a simple table where i tried to include the possible draws which can be made like this (which i think is my OPT function):

```
         4    7    2    3
       ------------------
a.  4 |  0   -3    2    1
      |
b.  7 |  3    0    5    4
      |
c.  2 | -2   -5    0   -1
      |
d.  3 | -1   -4    1    0
```

the left column marks player 1 draws, the upper row marks player 2 draws and each number then stands for `numberP1 - numberP2`. From this table i can at least read the above mentioned optimal strategy of 3 -> 4 -> 7 -> 2 (-1 + 5) so im sure that the table should contain all possible results, but im not quite sure now how to draw the results from it. I had the idea to start iterating over the rows and pick the one with the highest number in it and mark that as the pick from p1 (but that would be greedy anyways). p2 would then search this row for the lowest number and pick that specific entry which would then be the turn.

Example:

p1 picks row a. `7 |  3    0    5    4` since 5 is the highest value in the table. P2 now picks the 3 from that row because it is the lowest (the 0 is an invalid draw since it is the same number and you cant pick that twice) so the first turn would be 7 -> 4 but then i noticed that this draw is not possible since the 7 is not accessible from the start. So for each turn you have only 4 possibilities: the outer numbers of the table and the ones which are directly after/before them since these would be accessable after drawing. So for the first turn i only have rows a. or d. and from that p1 could pick:

4 which leaves p2 with 7 or 3. Or p1 takes 3 which leaves p2 with 4 or 2

But i dont really know how to draw a conclusion out of that and im really stuck.

So i would really like to know if im on the right way with that or if im overthinking this pretty much. Is this the right way to solve this?

Comment: Usually, to  get started with dynamic programming, you'll need a recurrence relation. Here it will be the following: `X(i, j) = max(Arr[i] + X(i+1, j), X(i, j-1) + Arr[j]` if `j-i == 0 % 2`, and `X(i, j) = min(Arr[i] + X(i+1, j), X(i, j-1) + Arr[j]` if `j-i == 1 % 2`. `X(i, j)` represents the best score that can be expected for player 1 with an optimal strategy. From this relation (and the trivial terminaison cases), you can built a dynamic programming algorithm by storing all the values of `X` as you calculate them.

Comment: @m.raynal i think that is the part which i dont really get. So i need to create a recurrence relation but how to approach that? Your examples are a bit hard to read (i think they miss some parenthesis too). So i somehow need to find this relation and then store the values into a matrix? And from that table i then search an optimal path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should try to write down, when starting a dynamic programming algorithm, is a recurrence relation.
Let's first simplify a very little the problem. We will consider that the number of cards is even, and that we want to design an optimal strategy for the first player to play. Once we have managed to solve this version of the problem, the others (odd number of cards, optimize strategy for second player) follows trivially.

So, first, a recurrence relation. Let `X(i, j)` be the best possible score that player 1 can expect (when player 2 plays optimally as well), when the cards remaining are from the `i^th` to the `j^th` ones. Then, the best score that player 1 can expect when playing the game will be represented by `X(1, n)`.
We have:
`X(i, j) = max(Arr[i] + X(i+1, j), X(i, j-1) + Arr[j])` if `j-i % 2 == 1`, meaning that the best score that player one can expect is the best between taking the card on the left, and taking the card on the right.
In the other case, the other player is playing, so he'll try to minimize:
`X(i, j) = min(Arr[i] + X(i+1, j), X(i, j-1) + Arr[j])` if `j-i % 2 == 0`.

The terminal case is trivial: `X(i, i) = Arr[i]`, meaning that when there is only one card, we just pick it, and that's all.

Now the algorithm without dynamic programming, here we only write the recurrence relation as a recursive algorithm:

```
function get_value(Arr, i, j) {
    if i == j {
        return Arr[i]
    } else if j - i % 2 == 0 {
        return max(
            Arr[i] + get_value(i+1, j),
            get_value(i, j-1) + Arr[j]
        )
    } else {
        return min(
            Arr[i] + get_value(i+1, j),
            get_value(i, j-1) + Arr[j]
        )
    }
}
```

The problem with this function is that for some given `i, j`, there will be many redundant calculations of `X(i, j)`. The essence of dynamic programming is to store intermediate results in order to prevent redundant calculations.

Algo with dynamic programming (X is initialized with `+ inf` everywhere.

```
function get_value(Arr, X, i, j) {
    if X[i][j] != +inf {
        return X[i][j]
    } else if i == j {
        result = Arr[i]
    } else if j - i % 2 == 0 {
        result = max(
            Arr[i] + get_value(i+1, j),
            get_value(i, j-1) + Arr[j]
        )
    } else {
        result = min(
            Arr[i] + get_value(i+1, j),
            get_value(i, j-1) + Arr[j]
        )
    }
    X[i][j] = result
    return result
}
```

As you can see the only difference with the algorithm above is that we now use a 2D array `X` to store intermediate results. The consequence on time complexity is huge, since the first algorithm runs in `O(2^n)`, while the second runs in `O(n²)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just dont really get what `X` in the second example is. One time it is used like an array the other time as a funtion. And i think i must be careful choosing min and max regarding on the oddness of the cards since it may happen that your start with an odd number of them and then player 1 would minimize instead of maximizing. I guess X is the mentioned array or matrix and should be used as an array?

Comment: About `X`: your edit was right, it should not appear in the first example. And it is an array (2D array), used to store intermediate values. Because if we do not store `X(2, 3)`, we will calculate it many times (from `X(1, 3)`, from `X(1, 4)` ....) , an exponential number of times actually. `X` is actually the only thing that really makes this code a DP code. About the min/max, order, bounds: yes, it is a bit laborious to write these parts without making mistakes.

Comment: Something else: When i hand-simulate the above algorithm for my example `4 7 2 3` i get 16 as a result. I have the feeling that the problem is, that i might need to return the end result of the match and not the single element score when reaching the end of the match `i == j`. So my return there would not be `Arr[i]` but rather `endscorep1 - endscorep2` which i could just exactly do as i did with my minimax function. Am i seeing this right, that i can just copy my minimax with the addition of the lookup to the array/table?

Comment: okay im lost again i tried to copy my minimax function and add the table lookup but of course it did not work. I figured out the obvious problem but i still dont know how to use the above function. What do the values which are returned mean?

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic programming problems can generally be solved in 2 ways, top down and bottom up.

Bottom up requires building a data structure from the simplest to the most complex case.  This is harder to write, but offers the option of throwing away parts of the data that you know you won't need again.  Top down requires writing a recursive function, and then [memoizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).  So bottom up can be more efficient, top down is usually easier to write.

I will show both.  The naive approach can be:

```
def best_game(numbers):
    if 0 == len(numbers):
        return 0
    else:
        score_l = numbers[0] - best_game(numbers[1:])
        score_r = numbers[-1] - best_game(numbers[0:-1])
        return max(score_l, score_r)
```

But we're passing a lot of redundant data.  So let's reorganize it slightly.

```
def best_game(numbers):
    def _best_game(i, j):
        if j <= i:
            return 0
        else:
            score_l = numbers[i] - _best_game(i+1, j)
            score_r = numbers[j-1] - _best_game(i, j-1)
            return max(score_l, score_r)

    return _best_game(0, len(numbers))
```

And now we can add a caching layer to memoize it:

```
def best_game(numbers):
    seen = {}
    def _best_game(i, j):
        if j <= i:
            return 0
        elif (i, j) not in seen:
            score_l = numbers[i] - _best_game(i+1, j)
            score_r = numbers[j-1] - _best_game(i, j-1)
            seen[(i, j)] = max(score_l, score_r)
        return seen[(i, j)]

    return _best_game(0, len(numbers))
```

This approach will be memory and time `O(n^2)`.

Now bottom up.

```
def best_game(numbers):
    # We start with scores for each 0 length game
    # before, after, and between every pair of numbers.
    # There are len(numbers)+1 of these, and all scores
    # are 0.
    scores = [0] * (len(numbers) + 1)
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        # We will compute scores for all games of length i+1.
        new_scores = []
        for j in range(len(numbers) - i):
            score_l = numbers[j] - scores[j+1]
            score_r = numbers[j+i] - scores[j]
            new_scores.append(max(score_l, score_r))
        # And now we replace scores by new_scores.
        scores = new_scores
    return scores[0]
```

This is again `O(n^2)` time but only `O(n)` space.  Because after I compute the games of length 1  I can throw away the games of length 0.  Of length 2, I can throw away the games of length 1.  And so on.

Comment: But how do you distinct the players? ALso my problem is what are the values which are returned what do they mean? i just dont get the "other way around" part. For example minimax has all possible results in the leafes and then you work your way up to the top where you get your final result. How does it work with DP? And what values can i store? FOr example if i have 4 7 2 3 and p1 picks 4 and p2 picks 3 the next step there is a decision (2,2) for which i store the value. But iwhat if p1 picks 3 and p2 4 then i also have (2,2) but with a different value.

Comment: @Yastanub Which player is which is implicit in the length of the stretch that is part of the sub game.  Evens are player A, odds are player B.  As for comparing to minimax, minimax can be computed by knowing the numbers at the ends and the scores of both smaller games.  Top down avoids having to calculate those scores multiple times.  In bottom up I go one better.  I can calculate games of length `i+1` from knowing the numbers and the scores of games of length `i`.  Then once I have all games of length `i+1` I never again need to look at games of length `i` and can throw away that data.

Comment: Okay ill take a deep look tomorrow i think i will not hit the deadline for my homework unfortunately but maybe i can at least understand this.